# AddressFilter mismatch when making soap call with cURL in php

Tags: php, web-services, curl, soap

I making SOAP calls through curl in php. But this error just pops out. I guess this comes because of the soap action which has been set properly and its not empty.

> The message with To '' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to an
>   AddressFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher.  Check that the
>   sender and receiver's EndpointAddresses agree.

I have no clue why this is coming. Am i missing something here or using something in the wrong place.

Here is my soap request

```
$soap_request = 
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:bses="http://bsestarmf.in/">
   <soap:Header>

   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <bses:getPassword>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <bses:UserId>123456</bses:UserId>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <bses:Password>789456</bses:Password>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <bses:PassKey>0123478</bses:PassKey>
      </bses:getPassword>
   </soap:Body>
 </soap:Envelope>';

$header = array(
    "Content-type: application/soap+xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
    "Accept: application/soap+xml",
    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
    "Pragma: no-cache",
    "SOAPAction: http://bsestarmf.in/MFOrderEntry/getPassword",
    "Content-length: ".strlen($soap_request),
);
$soap_do = curl_init();
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_URL,"http://bsestarmfdemo.bseindia.com/MFOrderEntry/MFOrder.svc" );
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POST,           true );
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     $soap_request);
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     $header);
$result = curl_exec($soap_do);

dd($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add

```
 <wsa:To>"http://bsestarmfdemo.bseindia.com/MFOrderEntry/MFOrder.svc"</wsa:To>
```

to your header xml